# Impedance matching on oscillator

Tags: oscillator, impedance-matching

I have built an oscillator configuration at 4-7GHz. At 5.29GHz, the output of the oscillator has resistance R=-189-j*51. How can I use impedance matching and a bandpass filter since I have a negative resistance, for my bandwidth?

Comment: Please post a schematic.  If your oscillator has a negative real part in its output impedance, you should probably seriously consider some sort of a buffer amplifier to isolate it from the outside world, or some passive isolation if you have power to spare in the isolator.  If you've got a one-device oscillator that is that strongly coupled to the oscillator, your output filter is going to pull it around.